# phpMyAdmin not working with nginx-proxy - php_network_getaddresses

Tags: docker, phpmyadmin, jwilder-nginx-proxy

I am trying to access **phpMyAdmin** behind **nginx-proxy** Docker image, hosted on my VPS.

When I try login in phpMyAdmin, I get the error: `php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known`

[image: error messages by phpMyAdmin]

The *docker-compose* file is:

```
version: "3"

services:
  mysql:
    build:
      context: "./bin/mysql8"
    container_name: 'mysql'
    restart: 'always'
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes: 
      - ./data/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./logs/mysql:/var/log/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${MYSQL_DATABASE}
      MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    container_name: 'sc-phpmyadmin'
    links:
      - mysql
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: mysql
      PMA_PORT: 3306
      PMA_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
      PMA_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
    expose:
      - 80
    environment:
       VIRTUAL_HOST: myadmin.example.com
       LETSENCRYPT_HOST: myadmin.example.com
    volumes: 
      - /sessions

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: nginx-proxy
```

The connection is protected with [letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion](https://github.com/JrCs/docker-letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion) (working correctly).
I have already read this thread about the error https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy/issues/596 ,  but there is no working solution.

Answer (score 0):

This should not be a proxy issue, since the connection from pma is happening directly at the server level. The proxy never gets to know this. Since You can access the pma container (you can see the login page), your proxy setup seems to be working correctly. Can you reach the mysql container from within the pma container?

Try running `docker-compose exec phpmyadmin bash` to get a shell running inside of the pma container and the run `ping mysql`.

You could also try to rename the `mysql` container to `db`, since the pma container will try to connect to a db at that host by default.

Last, you could try setting the `PMA_ARBITRARY=1` env variable at the pma container which will let you connect to any mysql server from it. There you can then try with either `mysql` or `db` or so.

(It could also be that the mysql container was not yet ready and therefore rejected the connection - but that would be a different error message).